# Stranded messaging Angular web app - main template for all views to live within

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular.js

I'm making an Angular web app to solve a pain with traditional messaging my friend and I had, of sending batches of messages (on multiple different topics) to each other every few hours and not having a UI optimized for that style of conversation.

I have a few concrete questions (and of course welcome anything else useful anyone notices):

1. Every new JS file (service, directive, everything) I add a line to the `head`. I've never had a `head` this large. Is there a more typical way of including all those files (maybe more modularized? or an automated tool?)?
2. `index.html` is the main template loaded, with a standard navbar at the top, and main content below. I do any "routing" with a couple controller variables (`mainCtrl.selected_user` determines whether it's in the chat view or the auth view and `mainCtrl.login_object` determines whether to see login or register within the auth view). That's perfectly feasible since I have so few different views (chat or auth, within auth login or register), but I have no need for this to be single-page, and I know there is a better routing method.

   The reason it is how it is now is because it was easy to share the main layout/styling across the different views, like the persistent navbar, and it's easy to share certain variables (see `mainCtrl.selected_user`) by passing it in to each directive. But now I want to add a user profile page, for example, and I feel like it should use real routing live at `/profile`, not just be another div in here shown or not by a controller variable.

   How does one achieve this, while still getting the benefits of the common layout/styling, and passing of variables?

```
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="Braid" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">

    <title ng-bind="mainCtrl.page_title">Braid</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/poop_logo.ico">

    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/objectid.js/src/main/javascript/Objectid.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-scroll-glue/src/scrollglue.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/enter_submit.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/navbar.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/register.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/login.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/logout.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives/friendships.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/filters/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/focus.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/socket.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/strands.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/convos.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/users.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/friendships.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/core.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Bootswatch Yeti -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/customize_bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/messages.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/users.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/friendships.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/firstview.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/register.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/logout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/typing_indicator.css">

</head>

<body>

    <braid-navbar login_object="mainCtrl.login_object"
                  selected_user="mainCtrl.selected_user"
                  page_title="mainCtrl.page_title"
                  sound_on="mainCtrl.sound_on">
    </braid-navbar>

    <div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="margin-fixer-grid-wrapper">

        <div id="chat-view" ng-if="mainCtrl.selected_user">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="message-view-col" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <braid-messages selected_convo="mainCtrl.selected_convo"
                                    selected_user="mainCtrl.selected_user"
                                    friend_user_map="mainCtrl.friend_user_map"
                                    page_title="mainCtrl.page_title"
                                    sound_on="mainCtrl.sound_on">
                    </braid-messages>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- slide in from right -->
            <braid-friendships friend_users="mainCtrl.friend_users"
                               friendships="mainCtrl.friendships"
                               selected_convo="mainCtrl.selected_convo"
                               selected_user="mainCtrl.selected_user"
                               friend_user_map="mainCtrl.friend_user_map">
            </braid-friendships>
        </div>


        <div id="auth-view" ng-if="!mainCtrl.selected_user">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <braid-register ng-hide="mainCtrl.login_object"
                                    selected_user="mainCtrl.selected_user"
                                    login_object="mainCtrl.login_object">
                    </braid-register>

                    <braid-login ng-show="mainCtrl.login_object"
                                 selected_user="mainCtrl.selected_user"
                                 login_object="mainCtrl.login_object">
                    </braid-login>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my opinions but hopefully these might help

1. Use [Grunt and Uglifyjs](http://sethlakowske.com/software/use-grunt-and-uglifyjs-to-combine-multiple-javascript-files-into-a-single-javascript-file/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org) or the most recent addition [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) which can package your complete site and will bring you closer to angular2 which you should be looking to do at this point.
2. Put the profile into a modal box and pop it over the other views so it can persist in state and be independent of the other two directives.